# How to resolve tcpdump dropped packets?

Tags: tcpdump

I am using tcpdump to capture network packets and running into issue when I start dropping packets. I ran an application which exchanges packets rapidly over network; resulting in high network bandwidth.

```
>> tcpdump -i eno1 -s 64 -B 919400
126716 packets captured
2821976 packets received by filter
167770 packets dropped by kernel
```

Since I am only interested in protocol related part from TCP packet; I want to collect TCP packets without data/payload. I hope this strategy can also help in capturing more packets before dropping packets. It appears that I can only increase buffer size (-B argument) upto certain limit. Even with higher limit I am dropping more packets than captured.

can you help me understanding above messages and questions I have

1. what are packets captured ?
2. what are packets received by filter?
3. what are packets dropped by kernel?
4. how can I capture all packets at high bandwidth without dropping any packets. My test application runs for 3 minutes and exchanges packets at a very high rate. I am only interested in protocol related information not in actual data/ payload being sent.

Answer (score 13):

From [Guy Harris](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/200911/msg00014.html) himself:

*the "packets captured" number is a number that's incremented every time tcpdump sees a packet, so it counts packets that tcpdump reads from libpcap and thus that libpcap reads from BPF and supplies to tcpdump.*

*The "packets received by filter" number is the "ps_recv" number from a call to pcap_stats(); with BPF, that's the bs_recv number from the BIOCGSTATS ioctl. That count includes all packets that were handed to BPF; those packets might still be in a buffer that hasn't yet been read by libpcap (and thus not handed to tcpdump), or might be in a buffer that's been read by libpcap but not yet handed to tcpdump, so it can count packets that aren't reported as "captured".*

And from the [`tcpdump` man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html):

*packets ``dropped by kernel'' (this is the number of packets that were dropped, due to a lack of buffer space, by the packet capture mechanism in the OS on which tcpdump is running, if the OS reports that information to applications; if not, it will be reported as 0).*

To attempt to improve capture performance, here are a few things to try:

- Don't capture in promiscuous mode if you don't need to.  That will cut down on the amount of traffic that the kernel has to process.  Do this by using the `-p` option.
- Since you're only interested in TCP traffic, apply a capture expression that limits the traffic to TCP only.  Do this by appending `"tcp"` to your command.
- Try writing the packets to a file (or files to limit size) rather than displaying packets to the screen.  Do this with the `-w file` option or look into the `-C file_size` and `-G rotate_seconds` options if you want to limit file sizes.
- You could try to improve `tcpdump`'s scheduling priority via [`nice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice).

From Wireshark's [Performance](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Performance) wiki page:

- stop other programs running on that machine, to remove system load
- buy a bigger, faster machine :)
- increase the buffer size (which you're already doing)
- set a snap length (which you're already doing)
- write capture files to a RAM disk

Try using [PF_RING](http://www.ntop.org/products/packet-capture/pf_ring/).

You could also try using [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html) instead of `tcpdump`, although I would be surprised if the performance was drastically different.

You could try capturing with an external, dedicated device using a TAP or Switch+SPAN port.  See Wireshark's [Ethernet Capture Setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet) wiki page for ideas.

Another promising possibility: [Capturing Packets in Linux at a Speed of Millions of Packets per Second without Using Third Party Libraries](http://kukuruku.co/hub/nix/capturing-packets-in-linux-at-a-speed-of-millions-of-packets-per-second-without-using-third-party-libraries).

See also Andrew Brown's Sharkfest '14 [Maximizing Packet Capture Performance](https://sharkfest.wireshark.org/assets/presentations/I3:%20Sharkfest_2014_ABrown%20-%20Copy.pdf) document for still more ideas.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would try actually *lowering* the value of your `-B` option.
The unit is 1 KiB (1024 bytes), thus the buffer size you specified (`919400`) is almost 1 gigabyte.

I suppose you would get better results by using a value closer to your CPU cache size, e.g. `-B 16384`.